# Typescript cannot find method in definition file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an existing Javascript file named app.min.js which comes with a website template.  This file defines a function called pageSetUp that needs to be invoked when the DOM is loaded.

I have created a TypeScript definition file named app.d.ts which the following content:

```
interface App {
    pageSetUp();
}
```

It is referenced in the TypeScript file as follows:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/app.d.ts"/>
```

However, when add the following line to the constructor of this class like this:

```
module ViewModel {

    export class TableViewModel {


        constructor() {
           pageSetUp();
        }
     }
}
```

The build fails with error:  "Could not find symbol 'pageSetUp'.

What am I missing?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.d.ts` is defining a method on an interface called `App`, but the `TableViewModel` is trying to use a global function called `pageSetUp`, which is not defined.

Try this instead in `app.d.ts`:

```
declare function pageSetUp();
```

This declares a global function, but doesn't implement it, so no associated JavaScript is generated, but the function definition can be referenced from other TypeScript files.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Will read more on this.  It sounds like a TypeScript interface is defined only for corresponding javascript "namespaces".